# Override renderForm prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

I am looking to clean override the controller category by adding 3 additional fields. The fields go back up correctly when I save it correctly records in database however when I edit the category the field information does not go back up. Here is my override controller:

```
public function renderForm()
{
    $this->fields_form_override = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'switch',
            'label' => $this->l('Vente privée'),
            'name' => 'private_sell',
            'required' => false,
            'is_bool' => true,
            'values' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'private_sell_on',
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => $this->l('Yes')
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 'private_sell_off',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'label' => $this->l('No')
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'label' => $this->l('Date début vente'),
            'name' => 'date_start',
            'required' => false,
            'lang' => true
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'label' => $this->l('Date fin vente'),
            'name' => 'date_end',
            'required' => false,
            'lang' => true
        ),
    );

    return parent::renderForm();
}
```

I do not understand where the problem comes from. Do you have an idea ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your override must have 3 part:

1. Add new fields to database
2. Override class
3. Override controller

Did you do all?